# What does nested parenthese mean in bash?

Tags: bash

What does this code do?

```
set +e
( set -e
 "$@"
)
ret=$?
set -e
```

I don't understand code in parentheses?

Comment: I think this is more a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26063/how-are-parentheses-interpreted-at-the-command-line

Comment: It runs the commands in a subshell. It's a way to avoid having the `set -e` leak outside the subshell.

Comment: @tripleee and what does it do here? prints `$@`? runs `$@`?

Comment: `"$@"` is the list of arguments to the current script or function. The double quotes are significant and important (`$@` without quotes is basically always a bug).

Comment: @tripleee ya, I know that `$@` is a list of arguments, but what does it do in nested parentheses?

Comment: Exactly the same thing. It contains the arguments of the function or script these nested parentheses are in. Maybe it gets called something like `noerror echo "hello there"` where you might have the function definition `noerror () { ( set -e; "$@" ); }`  and it thus end up executing `(set -e; echo "hello there" )`